# Why my MQTT client cannot reconnect when an exception occurs

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I implemented a service which uses an MQTT Client running in a separate thread from main. My MQTT Client is a class which inherits from pahoo's mqtt client. So I'm starting the loop as follows:

```
def run(self):
    logging.info("Starting MQTT Client")
    self.loop_start()
    self.connect(self._host, self._port, keepalive=self._timeout)
```

Then I add some specific callbacks to some topis, as this:

```
self.message_callback_add(topic, callback)
```

The problem is when any exception occurs inside the callback function, the MQTT Client's thread falls and never reconnects again. There is any way of preveting this without put a try catch clause surrounding all my callback?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: We will need more information here, by default the callbacks are run the a try/expect block that catches any exceptions (and ignores then). Edit the question to show the callbacks and the exceptions. Also can you not add your own try/expect block to the callback? You are responsible for dealing with the errors in your code

Comment: Add one of these callback functions to your post, and tell us specifically where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the behaviour [changed](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt) in release v1.5.1 so that exceptions in callbacks are no longer just ignored

> Exceptions that occur in callbacks are no longer suppressed by
> default. They   can optionally be suppressed by setting
> `client.suppress_exceptions = True`.   Closes #365.

So you have 2 choices:

1. set the `client.suppress_exceptions = True` to have the client silently consume the errors.
2. Add a `try/expect` block to wrap all the content of your callback, and handle the exception.